# When is the standard deviation of the squares of a random number greater than the square of the standard deviation of those numbers?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, variance, standard-deviation

I was playing around with the uncertainty of the kinetic energy operator in quantum mechanics, and really desired to have the following inequality be true:
$$\Delta K=\frac{1}{2m}\Delta (p^2)\geq\frac{1}{2m}(\Delta p)^2\geq\frac{\hbar^2}{8m(\Delta x)^2},$$
where $\Delta Q$ is the uncertainty (standard deviation) in variable $Q$ and the last step follows from the Heisenberg uncertainty principle. The problem is, $\Delta(Q^2)\geq(\Delta Q)^2$ turns out not to be true in general. I ran some sample distributions in Mathematica, and while this inequality is true most of the time, there are exceptions, though in those cases the difference is generally slight.

Is there a condition we can apply (distribution or allowed range of $Q$) that will enforce this inequality? If not, "how often" does the inequality fail? Expanding in terms of expectation values (after squaring to get a variance on the left and not have square roots) doesn't seem to help:
$$\langle Q^4\rangle\geq 2\langle Q^2\rangle(\langle Q^2\rangle-\langle Q\rangle^2)+\langle Q\rangle^4,$$
even though we know $\langle Q^4\rangle\geq \langle Q^2\rangle^2\geq \langle Q\rangle^4$.

Comment: If the absolute value of each number is larger than 1, the standard devitation of the squares will be larger than the square of the standard deviation. and if they're all between -1 a +1 the other way around. For mixed cases I guess that depends on the probability masses in (-1,1) and outside of it.

Comment: One case where it fails badly is if $Q=\pm q$ with equal probability. In that case $Q^2=q^2$ with probability one, so $\Delta(Q^2)=0$. But then $\Delta Q=q$. This moreover means the difference can be made arbitrarily large by increasing $q$. (I suppose one gets similar results by mixing two narrow Gaussian distributions centered at $\pm q$.)

Comment: In fact, there's a simple physical instance of the former example. Take the mixture of plane waves $\psi=e^{ikx}+e^{-i kx}$. Since it has wavenumbers $\pm k$ with equal probability, there is momentum dispersion. But the wavefunction has no dispersion in kinetic energy.

Comment: @Patricio: This doesn't seem to be the case in light of Semiclassical's remark; q can be of any magnitude, but in their case we still have $\Delta(Q^2)=0<(\Delta Q)^2=q^2$. I like the example of the dispersive plane waves; I wonder if restricting to only bound states where $\langle p\rangle=0$ changes anything?